# Flexigrid with IE6 show only headers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, flexigrid

I'm using flexigrid with `jquery-1.2.3.pack.js`. It works fine with Firefox but when I try IE6, it shows only headers.

I've found a discussion on the same bug, and it says to comment this line from `flexigrid.js`:

```
if (p.width!='auto') g.gDiv.style.width = p.width + 'px';
```

Tried with this but it dont show the grid.

Comment: Do you have some live example?

Comment: not yet, i'm working on local with xampp

Comment: Dont know why, but downloading again the flexigrid.js file and commenting the line as said above works perfectly... a bit slow on ie6, but no bugs to any feature.

Comment: Please move the answer-part of your question into a real answer below. Then mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know why, but downloading again the flexigrid.js file and commenting the line as said above works perfectly... a bit slow on ie6, but no bugs to any feature.